# Macroregional or Macro-Regional?

Tags: orthography, hyphenation

I have searched for the correct spelling of "macroregional / macro-regional" on the Internet, but there are used both variants (sometimes even on the same [website](https://ec.europa.eu/regional_policy/en/policy/cooperation/macro-regional-strategies/)).

[Wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/macroregional) spells it as "macroregional" but also suggests "macro-regional" as an alternative form.

Some other websites ([like this one](https://pjp-eu.coe.int/en/web/cultural-routes-and-regional-development/eu-macro-regions)) use only "macro-regional".

I need to choose only one variant for an article. Which spelling is correct among those two? Or are they both interchangeable? I will be grateful for your help.

P. S. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macroregion), as a noun it is "macroregion".

Comment: Hello, Michael. As this word and the associated noun are new/ish terms, there's probably disagreement over the best choices of spelling. No really respected dictionary seems to have picked up on the terms yet; the hyphenated form for the adjective and (perversely) the solid form for the noun 'macroregion' seem to be preferred (possibly because  _macroregional_ might be seen as internally garden-pathy, hard to pronounce at first sight). Since hyphenated words often progress quite rapidly to the unhyphenated ones, and because the noun seems preferred sans hyphen, I'd go unhyphenated.

Comment: Thank you for your help. There are some more adjectives starting with the prefix "macro" (e. g. macroscopic, macrocyclic, macrophagic, macrocosmic), so I also suppose that the unhyphenated form ("macroregional") is better.